# df.fillna(df.mean()) vs df.fillna(df.mean)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm puzzled by this. To `fillna` with mean, I should use `df.fillna(df.mean())` but I made the mistake of dropping the bracket `df.fillna(df.mean)`

I got a totally different result.  The documentation for `fillna` does accept a `scalar, dict, Series, or DataFrame` but when I type: `type(df.mean)` I got a `method` as `type` which does not make any sense.  It's not any of the `scalar, dict, Series, or DataFrame` accepted by fillna.

What is actually happening here?   I hope somebody could help enlighten me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the method itself is used as a fill value, as a **scalar**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, np.nan]})
df.fillna(df.mean)
```

so no surprise here:

```
    a
0   1
1   <bound method DataFrame.mean of a\n0 1.0...
```

it is like you do `df.fillna(lambda x: "some func")`

Comment: ic.  so the filled value is not a number.  Thanks...